# Need help making a miles walked program

Tags: c#, type-conversion, user-input

I have been working on this for hours and cannot create a program that will work and I really need help. I don't know what I am doing wrong. The steps are to Find the average stride by multiplying height by .413. Then divide that by 12 to get that in feet. the multiply by 2 to get feet walked. then divide by 5280 to get miles walked. I really cannot figure out what to do and help would be appreciated. I have little coding experience and just need help taking the user input and converting that data in order to get an answer.

```
        float Height;
        float Steps;

        float CON_FAC;
        float FEET_IN_Mile;
        float strideLength;
        float averageStride;
        float strideLength;
        float feetWalked; 
        float milesWalked;

        Console.Write("Input height(inches): ");
    Height = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Input Steps(today):");
    Steps = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

    CON_FAC = .413;
    FEET_IN_Mile = 5280;
    strideLength = Height * CON_FAC;
    averageStride = strideLength / 12;
    feetWalked = averageStride * Steps;
    milesWalked = feetWalked / FEET_IN_Mile
    Console.WriteLine("You walked "milesWalked" miles");'''
```

Comment: My advice is figure out the math with a pen and paper. That is if you believe you have a math error.  I am not exactly sure what you think the issue is. With that said I have not checked your math.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is but your code does not compile. This does

```
float Height;
float Steps;
float CON_FAC;
float FEET_IN_Mile;
float strideLength; // declare once
float averageStride;
float feetWalked; 
float milesWalked;

Console.Write("Input height(inches): ");
Height = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Input Steps(today):");
Steps = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

CON_FAC = .413F; // append F to make it a float
FEET_IN_Mile = 5280;
strideLength = Height * CON_FAC;
averageStride = strideLength / 12;
feetWalked = averageStride * Steps;
milesWalked = feetWalked / FEET_IN_Mile; // need ;
Console.WriteLine($"You walked {milesWalked} miles"); // changed to string interpolation
```

Comment: sorry I don't really have a question I just can't get it to run and do not know what my problem is. I need the it to ask the user for his height and steps taken and calculate how many miles they walked and I cannot even get it to ask the user for their inputs.

Comment: My answer runs. Have you even looked at it?